# How to output only drop-downs with values (and give them a name) - Contact Form 7

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I'm trying to create a quote request form for a client using Contact 7 in Wordpress. 
They've given me a couple of pages of products in a table and wants the user to be able to select an amount for each product from a drop-down and then have an email send to him telling him the user has requested a quote for the product(s) they selected in the form.

Ideally I would like only the items that have had a value selected to get sent in the email to my client.

Here's the setup I am using so far:

```
Product 1
[select menu-940 include_blank "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" ">10"]
Product 2
[select menu-941 include_blank "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" ">10"]
```

But many more lines of this. And the output code is:

```
[your-name] <[your-email]> is interested in the following products:

[menu-940]
[menu-941]
```

Of course just using the short code only displays a numerical value. Is there a way to have them show a text value and numerical value when there is a value selected, and not show at all if there is no value? Perhaps with a placeholder of some kind?

I have the "Exclude lines with blank mail-tags from output" box checked, so if menu-940 has no value, it won't be displayed; but still, a numerical value is of no use to anyone without some sort of identifier.

It would be awesome if I could get the drop-down to sit next to the name of the product in the form as well, as currently they take up an entire line each, making for a form that is twice as long as it needs to be.

Thanks a lot in advance. If this is hard to follow I'd be happy to provide more info.

Adam.

Comment: Do you have to use Contact form 7 plugin? If the e-commerce is quite advanced, it will be a good idea to use plugin like WooCommerce.

Comment: Please add some HTML markup to your question, so we can help you to position the elements next to each other.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. @PawełJanicki There is no HTML markup currently, this is just in the Contact form 7 form editor, just short code is being used at the moment. This is what I need help with. I tried using basic divs but to no avail. I am using woocommerce for the store, but this is a separate function for bulk order quotes. The products that will be quoted will vary in price vey often and cannot be implemented into a store easily. Also they are not stocked by the client, hence quoting, not straight up selling.. Thanks for your replies

Comment: No problem @MISQ, does my answer solve your issue with having different value/text for drop-down option? I know that Contact From 7 shortcodes don't contain HTML, but they render the markup, so you can check it in dev tools.

Comment: @PawełJanicki it didn't directly solve my issue, but it did lead me to solving it! - Thank you! For those who might find this later:
I took the products spreadsheet and used an HTML table generator, copied & pasted the data into that and used a table layout to format the data and the form itself. Not exactly the height of sophistication, but it'll do. Then I used the product names with the shortcodes of each dropdown from the form for the email output (i.e. [menu-101]). It doesn't show the output of anything that has no value from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56042/contact-form-7-select-box-different-value-text-then-content-text-in-option

It will solve your problem with different value/text for drop-down options.

When it comes to displaying the drop-down to next to the name of the product, you should play around with CSS to position it right.